# MySQL row into number of columns and sum

Tags: mysql, sql

Could somebody help with my SQL?

I have a table with records such as:

```
ID | Car_num | Service | Price
---+---------+---------+------
1  | 001     | shower  | 10
2  | 002     | TV      |  5
3  | 001     | TV      |  5
```

How to write an SQL query to get the following output?

```
ID |Car_num | shower | TV
---+--------+--------+---
1  | 001    | 10     | 5
2  | 002    |  0     | 5
```

Comment: in your expect out put TV is show as column header, is the expect out put is correct? can u recheck it once?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, Car_num
   , SUM(IF(Service = 'shower', Price, 0)) AS Shower
   , SUM(IF(Service = 'TV', Price, 0)) AS TV
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Car_num;
```

Comment: This query won't even run on certain versions of MySQL.

Comment: Not your machine, your version of MySQL.  On some versions of MySQL and virtually all other RDMBS, `SELECT ID` would generate an error, because `ID` is not specified in `GROUP BY` or wrapped in an aggregate function.

Comment: Id is nonsensical here

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Did you mean only_full_group_by SQL_MODE? It only enabled on MySQL 5.7.5 and newer.

Comment: Just wrap `ID` in `MAX`, `MIN`, etc., or leave it out completely.

Answer (score 3):

Use a pivot query:

```
SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID,
       Car_num,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Service = 'shower' THEN Price ELSE 0 END) AS shower,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Service = 'TV'     THEN Price ELSE 0 END) AS TV
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Car_num
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Car_num) Id,Car_num ,ISNULL([TV],0) [TV],ISNULL([shower],0) [shower]
```

FROM 
(
   SELECT Car_num , _Service , ISNULL(Price,0) Price
   FROM #Table
)Data
PIVOT
(
  MAX(Price) FOR _Service IN ([TV],[shower])
)AS PVT